# Adding a background to webpage using reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to add a background to a webpage using reactjs. However, I am having issues using the correct HTML script. I have set the value of a constant variable to an  element, but I am unsure of why to place it in my HTML script in order to show a background after being compiled.

```
import { animals } from './animals';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const title = (name === '' ? 'Wyatt Railey': name);
const animalFact = (<div background:{background}>
  <h1>
    {title}
  </h1>
</div>);
const background = <img className='background'
alt='ocean'
src='./images/ocean.jpg' />

ReactDOM.render(animalFact, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Use CSS styling to add background. Check this https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images_background.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am not sure if its valid

```
background:{background}
```

probably meant

```
background={background}
```

But, still, i dont think its still correct, as ur not using any package to make background work. i recommend using css.

If ur trying to set the bg, i would suggets two approach,

- add the `img`, and add css to make it fixed on the page, negative `z-index` to not interfare with page,
- Or, Simply use css to add background-image in the parent component (which is rendered by ReactDOM.render)